# How to update number sequence column when remove item from item detail in html table

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, sequence

I'm making an invoice in which order has more than one product order detail table which has number of product column sequence no. for each added product row by user, when user add some product detail rows in it the number of product column sequence auto update by this code:

```
var n = $(".detail tr").length-0)+1;
var tr = '<td class="no">'+ n +'</td>'
```

when user want to remove one of the product detail between added rows the no. of sequence column not update how I can do that?

Comment: Let's seem some code, please.  What have you tried? We can help you with your existing code, but we aren't a code-writing service!

Comment: hello I am newbie of HTML and JavaScript. i am trying to update auto increment column number sequence  when user delete some row between ad

Comment: @cale_b i found how to do it check my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
 $(function()
 {
      // Add Row
  $("#add").click(function()
  {
   addnewrow();
  });
      
      // Remove Row
       $("body").delegate('#remove','click',function()
  {
   $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  }); 
      
    });
 function addnewrow()
 {
  var tr = '<tr>' +
                   '<td class="count"></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" class="productname"></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="button" value="-" id="remove"></td>'+
                  '</tr>'
  $(".detail").append(tr);
 }
```

```css
body {counter-reset:section;}
.count:before
{
counter-increment:section;
content:counter(section);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
    <th><input type="button" value="+" id="add"></th>  
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="detail">
    <tr>
      <td class="count"></td>
       <td><input type="text" class="productname"></td>
       <td><input type="button" value="-" id="remove"></td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Update Name attribte Increment in each row
$('#dataTable tbody tr').each(function () {
    var this_row = $(this);
    var rowIndex = this_row.index();
    $.each(this_row.find(':input'), function (i, val) {
        var oldName = $(this).attr('name');
        var newName = oldName.replace(/\d+/, rowIndex);
        $(this).attr('name', newName);
    });
});
```